# Can you pre-process an XML file in Java to make loading/further processing faster?

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

I'm wondering whether I can improve String processing in my application.
I created a test XML [ for RSS, because I'm a wannabe Columbus ] 6.7 MB file and I'm processing the text to fit line length through a RegEx:

```
String returnString=returnString+"Text      : " + 
 e.getChildText("description").
replaceAll("(?<=\\G.{70,81}(?=\\s))",
"\n           ")+" \n";
```

Each processed item [ org.jdom2.Element ] takes about 8-16 ms [ Intel i7 gen 7, laptop ], so I wasn't as unhappy before I made it chew through an almost 7 MB file.

It takes 65-75 seconds to process.

Can I do some kind of pre-processing to speed the process up, or is this it?

Other languages / other approaches are entirely welcome. Except C.

Edit: I'm processing a String inside of a org.jdom2.Element.

Comment: What is the current bottleneck? If you don’t know, you may want to learn to use a profiler. The one in visualvm is a good place to start.

Comment: I don't see the bottleneck. I don't even know if there is one. I wrote a code that I thought was good, but I don't like the output processing time. It seems long to me. I may be doing a "mother-in-law". Frankly, I posted a code that may be useful to some people [ well, the regex could ] and I'm wondering about the improvements, since I lack further knowledge.

Literally academic, but useful for everyone else.

Comment: Consider using a simpler regular expression.

Comment: Hm... Kindly explain. Consider me an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to word-wrap the text to lines of 70-81 characters, with wrapped lines indented 11 spaces so they are up to 92 characters wide?

Comment: Well, that is the exercise, Andreas. Basically n-m word-wrap while processing an jdom.Element.

Comment: Is this question about the Processing language? If not, please remove the [tag:processing] tag. The [tag:processing] tag is not meant for general processing questions.

Comment: @user1628658 Sorry, but that's not how this works. The [tag:processing] tag is for the Processing language. What would the point of a general processing tag even be? Good luck with your question, but it does not belong in the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: Well then, I would kindly ask you to edit the tag [ since I cannot ] to process-string or similar. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a single change, unlikely.

If you're making several changes, then quite likely.

If you're running several regexes, then you're constantly iterating across, copying, and modifying the string several times.

At some point it is cheaper to parse the XML once (in to a DOM, for example), iterate over it at a high level making smaller changes, and then rendering the XML back out in to the string. Where the cross over point is depends on the overall size of the string, number of changes, cost of parsing and rendering, etc. So, best to try and make some benchmarks to see what works better.

Comment: As common with programming, I'm talking about constant programmatic change. Therefore I'm asking about as low numbers as I can get.

Comment: Sure, but somethings that are expensive to set up are worth while in the long run if you can take advantage of the efficiencies they provide. So it's important to understand the costs of "speeding something up" to see if they're worthwhile in the end for your use case.